# Pagination on custom post type is not working when clicking on next link

Tags: pagination

Trying to paginate custom post types of specific taxonomy but next link of pagination is not working and getting **404 page**.
any help

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'my_product',
            'taxonomy'=>$taxonomy->name,
            'posts_per_page'=> 1,
            'term'=>$term->slug,
            'paged'=>$paged
                );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail('featured');
                } ?>
        <div class="caption caption-content">
        <h3 class="product-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p class="text-muted">&nbsp;&nbsp; تاریخ: <?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
            <div>
            <p class="price-box">
            <i class="fa fa-circle">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>قیمت:
                <?php if (the_field('price') == '') {
                    } else {
                    the_field('price');
                            } ?>
                </p>

                </div>
                    </div>
                <hr>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                }
                else {
                    echo '<h3>هیچ موردی درین بخش یافت نشد.</h3>';
                }
                ?>
                <!-- pagination here -->
                <?php wp_reset_postdata();
                 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',  // if using pretty permalink
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $query->max_num_pages ) );
 $posts_per_page
                ?>
```